# shared_ptr from unique_ptr of abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract, unique-ptr, make-shared

I'm trying to follow Herb Sutter's C++ guidelines, in this case to prefer `unique_ptr` to raw pointers and `shared_ptr`. One of the arguments in favour of `std::unique_ptr` is convertibility to `shared_ptr` should that be needed at some point.

In my case I have a `vector` of `unique_ptr` that I need to pass to a method that takes a `vector` of `shared_ptr`. I was hoping to be able to write something like:

```
for (auto &uniquePtr : vectorUnique)
    vectorShared.push_back(make_shared<Abstract>(move(uniquePtr));
```

This gives me the following error with my `Xcode 7.1` based toolchain configured for `C++11`:

> error: field type 'Abstract' is an abstract class.

It seems the STL is trying to hold a concrete instance of type `Abstract` when I use `make_shared`. That would seem to make Mr. Sutter's advice unworkable in many cases, so I'm sure I must be doing something wrong! I've resorted to writing:

```
for (auto &uniquePtr : vectorUnique) {
    auto ptr = uniquePtr.get();
    auto shared = shared_ptr<Abstract>(ptr);
    vectorShared.push_back(shared);
    uniquePtr.release();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You want `shared_ptr<Abstract>`, not `make_shared<Abstract>`. That constructor isn't explicit, either, so you can just write `push_back(std::move(uniquePtr))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`make_shared` constructs a new object using the given arguments and returns a `shared_ptr` to it.  So the compiler expects a constructor `Abstract(std::unique_ptr<Abstract>)`, which is probably not what you have.

What you want is the constructor of `shared_ptr` that takes a `unique_ptr` argument:

```
    vectorShared.push_back(shared_ptr<Abstract>(move(uniquePtr)));
```

and, as it's not `explicit`, then

```
    vectorShared.emplace_back(move(uniquePtr));
```

will just work (I've used `emplace_back` to avoid redundant copying, at Richard Hodges's suggestion).  There's even a standard algorithm, so you don't need the `for` loop:

```
    std::move(vectorUnique.begin(), vectorUnique.end(),
              std::back_inserter(vectorShared));
```

---

If you need this regularly, you might define a function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>
        convert_to_shared(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>&& vu)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> vs;
    vs.reserve(vu.size());
    std::move(begin(vu), end(vu), std::back_inserter(vs));
    return vs;
}


// Example of use
class Abstract {};
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Abstract>> vectorUnique;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Abstract>> vectorShared
        = convert_to_shared(std::move(vectorUnique));
}
```

Sorry about the terrible name (I'm open to suggestions).  If you omit the call to `reserve()`, you could generalise it to more containers.

Comment: `vectorShared.emplace_back(move(uniquePtr))` - avoids a redundant conversion.

Comment: Good of you to mention me. I also think emplace_back will work if the constructor is explicit. Nice answer.

Comment: Thinking about it, there's no advantage - `push_back` is overloaded to accept rvalues, and should be equivalent to `emplace_back` in this case?

Comment: not quite. there's still one more redundant move with push_back - even with copy elision.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
for (auto &uniquePtr : vectorUnique) {
    vectorShared.emplace_back(std::move(uniquePtr));
}
```

Comment: This leaks if the vector's reallocation throws.

Comment: shared_ptr is constructible from an r-value reverence to a unique_ptr. no need to release - simply move.